# Power Series Representation/Interval of Convergence for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Am I correct in the assumption that
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}$$
is the correct power series representation of the function? I tried taking the ratio test to find the interval of convergence here:
$$\lvert\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}\rvert\rightarrow\lvert\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{x^{2n}}\rvert\rightarrow\lvert\frac{x^{2n+2}}{x^{2n}}\rvert\rightarrow\lvert{x^{2n+2-2n}}\rvert\rightarrow\lvert{x^{2}}\rvert$$
$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert{x^{2}}\rvert = \infty$$
But I'm stuck here. I've learned two seemingly conflicting rules about the interval of convergence for a function like this. 
The first rule: if $L$ evaluates to infinity, then the series only converges when $x = c$, where $c$ is the "offset" of $x$. It appears to me that $c$ in this case would be $0$, so the series only converges at $x=0$. 
However, the second rule states that the interval of convergence lies where $\lvert{L}\rvert < 1$. In this case, I would attempt to take the square root of all sides. Since $\lvert{x^2}\rvert$ is just $x^2$:
$$\sqrt{-1}<\sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{1}\ \rightarrow$$
$${i}<x<\pm1$$
which doesn't really make much sense to me. Looking at the graph, it appears to diverge at $x = -1$ and $x=1$ and converge when $x<-1$ and $x>1$. 
Also, if I could get clarification on the names of the rules I'm using throughout this post, that'd help my understanding.

Comment: To apply the ratio test, write the power series as $\sum a_nx^n$. Here $a_n=1$ when $n$ is even and $a_n=0$ when $n$ is odd. So $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is ill-defined when $n$ is odd and so the ratio test fails. You could use the root test instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to note that the power series
$$
f(u) = \frac{1}{1-u} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n
$$
is valid for $|u| < 1$. Similarly, if we let $u = x^2$, we get your power series for $$|u|^2 < 1 \iff |u| < 1.$$

---

If you like, you can use the ratio test. Let $a_n = x^{2n}$ then
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{x^{2n}} = x^2,
$$
which converges if the RHS < 1, resulting in the same inequality.